# NameError: name 'x2' is not defined

Tags: python, nameerror

I am trying to read data from a senor using my PI and in order to calculate the magnitude to determine acceleration but but I always get the following error when I run a test program

```
Time elasped: 0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "MMA7455.py", line 47, in <module>
    print("X = ", x2)
NameError: name 'x2' is not defined
```

This is the the code that ive been using

```
def calculateMag():
   x = MMA7455.getValueX()
   x2 = ((x + 128) % 256) -128

   y = MMA7455.getValueY()
   y2 = ((y - 240 + 128) % 256) -128

   z = MMA7455.getValueZ()
   z2 = ((z - 64 + 128) % 256) -128

   magnitude = int(math.sqrt((x2*x2) + (y2*y2) + (z2*z2)))

return x2, y2, z2, magnitude

for i in range (1000):
   timeGo()
   calculateMag()
   print("X = ", x2)
   print("Y = ", y2)
   print("Z = ", z2)
```

Ive tried passing x, y, z into the function but this didnt seem to work.Thanks for the help it would be much appreciated.

Comment: `x2` is out of scope when you try to print it. It's not a global variable.

Comment: assign the variables: `x2, y2, z2, magnitude = calculateMag()`

Answer (score 0):

When you return values from a function, the variable names that you gave to them within the function don't necessarily still exist outside of that function. In your case, when you call `calculateMag()`, the return values aren't going anywhere. Try this:

```
x2,y2,z2,magnitude = calculateMag()

print("X = ", x2)
print("Y = ", y2)
print("Z = ", z2)
```